# Paypal PHP SDK: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Paypal\Rest\ApiContext' not found

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

I'm trying to integrate PayPal, for express checkout with their PHP SDK. Unfortunately though, I'm getting the following error:

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Paypal\Rest\ApiContext' not found"

However, I can't see anything at all wrong with my code:

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$paypal = new \Paypal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \Paypal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
);
```

I have been through the documentation on this, and it hasn't really been of any help to me. My code is identical to that within the PayPal documentation, and I downloaded and placed their SDK files exactly as advised within the documentation. Unfortunately, I can not see what the issue is.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`PayPal`, not `Paypal` (notice the capital P). So you want:

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$paypal = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the first '\' before your Paypal class name.

Replace this :
`$paypal = new \Paypal\Rest\ApiContext`

By This: 
`$paypal = new Paypal\Rest\ApiContext`

You also need to replace `new \Paypal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)`

By `new Paypal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this, but unfortunately made no difference to the error I am receiving. Just pops up with the same error sadly.

Comment: On the "Paypal PHP SDK" github page, there is no "autoload.php". What is your vendor/autoload.php code ?